# How to debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS caused by Interface Builder binding?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, exc-bad-access, cocoa-bindings

This question should not be about a specific problem, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261045/how-do-i-ask-a-question-about-a-problem-with-xib-file) for more details.

Suppose I have an NSTableView with one column of which the Value has been bound to an ArrayController (bound to a property on the window controller). I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The question is how to debug this. I thought of two steps:

1. Get a stacktrace.
2. Use `NSZombieEnabled`.

Both didn't help:

```
#0  0x00007fff833f6696 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x00007fff833f2a38 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x00007fff89be9d08 in -[NSValueBinder displayValueForObjectValue:] ()
#3  0x00007fff89be9ab7 in -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] ()
#4  0x00007fff89d47e75 in -[NSValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] ()
#5  0x00007fff89d47d83 in -[NSTextValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] ()
#6  0x00007fff89d47d30 in -[_NSBindingAdaptor tableColumn:willDisplayCell:row:] ()
#7  0x00007fff89c31b00 in -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] ()
#8  0x00007fff89c4a963 in -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] ()
#9  0x00007fff89c499fc in -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] ()
#10 0x00007fff89c492ef in -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] ()
#11 0x00007fff89c47c9c in -[NSTableView drawRect:] ()
#12 0x00007fff89c3dd75 in -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] ()
#13 0x00007fff89c3b54b in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#14 0x00007fff89c3bed6 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#15 0x00007fff89c3bed6 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#16 0x00007fff89c3bed6 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#17 0x00007fff89c3bed6 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#18 0x00007fff89c3bed6 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#19 0x00007fff89c3bed6 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#20 0x00007fff89c3ab2c in -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#21 0x00007fff89c373de in -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] ()
#22 0x00007fff89bb0c0e in -[NSView displayIfNeeded] ()
#23 0x00007fff89bababa in _handleWindowNeedsDisplay ()
#24 0x00007fff833e3b07 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#25 0x00007fff833bf434 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#26 0x00007fff833bed8f in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#27 0x00007fff83d0a7ee in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#28 0x00007fff83d0a551 in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#29 0x00007fff83d0a4ac in BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode ()
#30 0x00007fff89b80eb2 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#31 0x00007fff89b80801 in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#32 0x00007fff89b4668f in -[NSApplication run] ()
#33 0x00007fff89b3f3b0 in NSApplicationMain ()
#34 0x0000000100001789 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff628) at /redacted/main.m:13
```

This only tells me that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is caused by the binding of the table view. The binding is accessing some variable that does not exist. Enabling `NSZombieEnabled` tells me the accessed variable is of type 'CFString', obviously I needed to use more than one string, so that information is not really helpful either. How do I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried exception breakpoint?

Comment: Yields some assembly instructions, not useful.

Comment: @Kreiri Errors are in IB bindings so I am not sure if exception breakpoint will help OP here.

Comment: Pain, but... subclass the tableview just to override `preparedCellAtColumn:row:` which is in your call stack?  Call the super method and then add a log line to inspect the cell's objectValue as well as row/col indices for the cell which is causing this issue.